# Capybara with Javascript (Rspec, Spork, and FactoryGirl to Boot)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rspec, capybara, spork

I've got an asynchronous javascript function I need to test with capybara.  I understand that I have to use the `js: true` option on the tests and set `config.use_transactional_fixtures = false`, then throw in some `database_cleaner`, but I still can't get it working.

The `cart_spec` runs through the whole process of adding an item to the cart and purchasing it (so it is nested pretty deep).

`checkout.html.erb` uses the `stripe` library to handle credit cards.  That has the javascript functionality I need to test.

When I run the tests with the `js: true` option, I get a test failure that 'Add to Cart' doesn't exist on the `sports_url`, indicating the sports aren't being saved to the database.

When I run the tests without the `js: true` option, all the tests pass except for `it "should warn user that cc number is invalid" do` because that is where the javascript is.

I'm running `spork` and have tried restarting the server.

**Edit**

The problem is that my test is running at the domain www.example.com, so my `sports_url` is being directed to www.example.com/sports.  I've asked a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694756/rails-test-environment-named-routes). If I access it with `sports_path`, it works great.

Here are the files:

cart_spec:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe "Cart" do
  before do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    @cart = @user.carts.create!
  end

  describe "using stripe" do
      before do
        @sport = FactoryGirl.create(:sport)
      end

      describe "user adds sport to cart", js: true do
        before do
          visit sports_url
          click_link "Add to Cart"
        end

        it "should be checkout page" do
          page.should have_content("Total")
        end

        describe "user clicks checkout" do
          before do
            click_button "Checkout"
          end

          it "should redirect user to sign in form" do
            page.should have_selector('h2', text: "Sign in")
          end

          describe "user logs on" do
            before do
              fill_in "Email", with: @user.email
              fill_in "Password", with: @user.password
              click_button "Sign in"

            end

            it "should be on checkout page" do
              page.should have_selector('h2', text: "Checkout")
            end

            describe "user fills in form" do
              context "with invalid cc number" do
                before do
                  fill_in "card-number", with: 42
                  click_button "Submit Payment"
                end

                it "should warn user that cc number is invalid" do
                  page.should have_content("Your card number is invalid")
                end
              end
            end

          end
        end
      end
  end

  describe "GET /carts/checkout" do
    subject { @cart }

    it { should respond_to(:paypal_url) }
    it { should respond_to(:apply_discount) }

    it "paypal_url contains notification" do
      @cart.paypal_url(root_url, payment_notifications_url).should include("&notify_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fpayment_notifications")
    end

    it "paypal_url contains invoice id" do
      @cart.paypal_url(root_url, payment_notifications_url).should match /&invoice=\d+&/
    end

    it "paypal_url contains return url" do
      @cart.paypal_url(root_url, payment_notifications_url).should include("&return=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com")
    end
  end

  describe "GET /carts/discount" do
    it "should apply discount to all line items" do
        @cart.line_items.build(:unit_price => 48)

        @cart.apply_discount

        @cart.line_items.each do |lineItem|
          lineItem.unit_price.should == 9.99
        end
    end
  end

end
```

checkout.html.erb:

```
<h2>Checkout</h2>
<span class="payment-errors"></span>
<form action="" method="POST" id="payment-form">
    <div class="form-row">
        <label>Card Number</label>
        <input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" id ="card-number" class="card-number"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label>CVC</label>
        <input type="text" size="4" autocomplete="off" class="card-cvc"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label>Expiration (MM/YYYY)</label>
        <input type="text" size="2" class="card-expiry-month"/>
        <span> / </span>
        <input type="text" size="4" class="card-expiry-year"/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="submit-button">Submit Payment</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v1/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_xIm00GVAKVLMWmfeR2J8GlmeHcyhL');

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#payment-form").submit(function(event) {
        // disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
        $('.submit-button').attr("disabled", "disabled");

        Stripe.createToken({
            number: $('.card-number').val(),
            cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
            exp_month: $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
            exp_year: $('.card-expiry-year').val()
        }, stripeResponseHandler);

        // prevent the form from submitting with the default action
        return false;
      });
    });

    function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
        if (response.error) {
            $('.submit-button').removeAttr("disabled");
            //show the errors on the form
            $(".payment-errors").html(response.error.message);
        } else {
            var form$ = $("#payment-form");
            // token contains id, last4, and card type
            var token = response['id'];
            // insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
            form$.append("<input type='hidden' name='stripeToken' value='" + token + "'/>");
            // and submit
            form$.get(0).submit();
        }
    }
</script>
```

spec_helper:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'

Spork.prefork do
  # Loading more in this block will cause your tests to run faster. However, 
  # if you change any configuration or code from libraries loaded here, you'll
  # need to restart spork for it take effect.
  # This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'rspec/autorun'

  # Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
  # in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    # == Mock Framework
    #
    # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
    #
    # config.mock_with :mocha
    # config.mock_with :flexmock
    # config.mock_with :rr
    config.mock_with :rspec

    # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
    config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

    # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
    # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
    # instead of true.
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

    # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
    # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
    # rspec-rails.
    config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

    config.before(:suite) do
        DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    end

    config.before(:each) do
        DatabaseCleaner.start
    end

    config.after(:each) do
        DatabaseCleaner.clean
    end
  end
end

Spork.each_run do
  # This code will be run each time you run your specs.

end
```

Comment: Hi friend, i dont know how to test my website with paypal accocunt with fake data, using capybara rspec,can you please help me ,i need to complete by tomorrow..

Comment: thanks for your reply,i have stuck on money transaction from my website to paypal (test) .what is my next step ? please reply as soon as possible...

Comment: you need to create a fake transaction?

Comment: yes ,but it should be using capybara...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was using `visit <route>_url`.  The default domain for rails tests is exmaple.com, so my browser was trying to access `www.example.com/sports`, which is kindly reserved by the international internet naming committee.

I changed those to `visit <route>_path` and things work great.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give you exact answer.

When you are running JS specs, there are 2 processes. And it is possible, that the record is not saved ye,t when you visit page in parallel process.

1. Try to wait until @sport is saved into the DB. 
   Add

`wait_until { page.has_content? "Add to Cart" }`

before

`click_link "Add to Cart"`

Capybara will wait for these words (2 seconds max). To increase the default wait time, add `Capybara.default_wait_time = 5` to spec_helper.

1. Be sure that the DatabaseCleaner strategy is really `:truncation`. I see your spec_helper. Just check it twice :)