# Rails Test Environment Named Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, environment

I've noticed that when I run tests (using Rspec and spork, if that matters), my hostname is set to www.example.com.  So if I do:

```
 visit sports_url
```

the test is actually going to www.example.com/sports.

This is a problem because I need to run some of the tests with selenium (to get javascript support).  Also, I noticed my emails where being marked as coming from www.example.com.

What did I mess up?  Why is the test environment running as example.com? Can I configure this somewhere? I would assume it should be programatic (depending on what port the test server starts up on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure the test environment domain, then set up DNS to do what you need.

[How do I change the default "www.example.com" domain for testing in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598933/how-do-i-change-the-default-www-example-com-domain-for-testing-in-rails)